# Modificar um Address com varios Offset

Tags: c#

Olá, tenho esse address `Game.exe + 01438C2C` e esses offset `0x0 0x3C 0xA6C` e gostaria de saber como modificar o o valor em hex deles. Ex: de `61 72 30 32` para `61 72 30 33`

Eu estava usando o writeprocessmemory com address "falso" porem preciso utilizar um pointer  e não sei como fazer isso. Grato

Comment: Uma quantidade maior de código ajudaria a solucionar o problema, creio eu.

Comment: Os detalhes estão vagos, poderia postar um fragmento do seu código e onde você teria que aplicar o tal ponteiro?

Answer (score 0):

Como você marcou a questão com a tag C#, acredito que esteja usando pinvoke com alguma definição da função [WriteProcessMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674(v=vs.85).aspx) em .net que faça o marshal da melhor forma para a sua necessidade. Porém acredito que a assinatura definida no [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.writeprocessmemory) seja suficiente.

Dito isso, assumindo que você tenha um hProcess válido para o seu Game.exe com as devidas permissões, você pode usar algo como:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, int nSize, IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

        private const int PROCESS_VM_WRITE = 0x0020;
        private const int PROCESS_VM_OPERATION = 0x0008;

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int processAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int processId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var game = Process.GetProcessesByName("game");
            if (game.Length > 0)
            {
                var hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION, false, game[0].Id);
                if (hProcess != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    var lpBaseAddress = new IntPtr(0xA6C);
                    var lpBuffer = new byte[] { 0x61, 0x72, 0x30, 0x33 };
                    if (WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, lpBaseAddress, lpBuffer, lpBuffer.Length, IntPtr.Zero))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Ok");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Falhou");
                    }

                    CloseHandle(hProcess);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Não foi possível abrir o processo (OpenProcess).");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Game não encontrado.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ps: tirei o `out` do último parâmetro do WriteProcessMemory pra pode passar o IntPtr.Zero ao invés de declarar uma váriável e ter que passar.